# How can I get all resource list programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, role, resources

I want to fetch all resource id(s) list programmatically in foreach loop.
In **System > Permission > Roles > Administrator** .
 In **Role Resources Tab** and select **custom** option from dropdown It will display all resources.This All **resources** want to fetch programmatically.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Tab/Rolesedit.php`. Look for method `getResTreeJson`. This method returns a json array of all resources.

Also you can just call this code:

```
$resources = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->getResourcesTree();
```

It returns a `Varien_Simplexml_Element` object.

Comment: Now I can fetch all resource list.Thanks for hint

Answer (score 1):

To have a list of the resources you can call this code:

```
$resources = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->getResourcesList2D();
```

This will return an array with all the path of the resources.

Answer (score 1):

```
$resources = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->getResourcesList();
```

for more information refer a http://sonimanthan228.blogspot.in/2015/12/fetch-all-resource-list-in-magento-by.html